# Problem using $.when() with post actions

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

when().then() pattern in the following situation:

```
$.when(setServerValue("true"))
    .then(function(){
        console.log('done setting new value');
        performSomeOperation();
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('server value not set!');
    });

var setServerValue = function(newValue){
    return $.post('http://myURL',{key:newValue});
};
```

The problem here is that the 'then' or 'fail' operations are never called using a $.post() operation. I've successfully used this approach with $.get() operations, and if I understand the API docs correctly (apparently not), this should also work for $.post operations.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `setServerValue()` is in scope at the time `$.when()` is called (as hoisting does not apply to function expressions IIRC). Can you try defining it as `function setServerValue(newValue) { ... }` and see if its fixes your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that setServerValue is not defined as function when you call it.  Move your definition of setServerValue above the $.when call.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/JHkKG/

Comment: Wow such a simple, but effective sollution. When i get the chance i'll try it with my development code. At least the jsfiddle works, so that means i understood the api docs correctly.. :-)